# How to return several columns from SQL functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a function that select 3 different columns from the same table and returns 3 columns. Instead of that, the function returns one columns which contains 3 strings.

I use Postgresql and pgAdmin4.
I wrote a function that take as parameter an integer and use it as WHERE condition in the request. It provides a good result but not yheway I expect.

My function's code:

```
create or replace function projetdep(dep integer) returns table (projet_nom varchar(100), projet_cdp_ineo varchar(100), projet_cdp_free  varchar(100))
language sql
as
$$
select projet_nom, projet_cdp_ineo,projet_cdp_free from projet where projet_departement = dep;
$$;

alter function projetdep(integer) owner to "userLyess";
```

And the result displayed is something like that:

```
("21021_001_01 - ARC SUR TILLE",FB,HS)
```

Which is 1 column

However I expect something like that:

```
21021_001_01 - ARC SUR TILLE;HS;FB
```

Which is 3 columns